# How to handle indices in Neo4j server via javascript REST client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, neo4j, d3.js

I have data in a standalone Neo4j REST server, including an index of nodes. I want pure JavaScript client to connect to Neo4j and serve the formatted data to d3.js, a visualisation library built on Node.js.

JugglingDB is very popular, but the Neo4j implementation was done "wrong": https://github.com/1602/jugglingdb/issues/56

The next most popular option on github is: https://github.com/thingdom/node-neo4j
looking at the method definitions https://github.com/thingdom/node-neo4j/blob/develop/lib/GraphDatabase._coffee

I'm able to use "getNodeById: (id, _) ->"

```
> node1 = db.getNodeById(12, callback);
```

returns the output from the REST server, including node properties. Awesome.

I can't figure out how to use "getIndexedNodes: (index, property, value, _) ->"

```
> indexedNodes = db.getIndexedNodes:(index1, username, Homer, callback);
...
```

indexedNodes don't get defined. I've tried a few different combinations. No joy. How do I use this command?

Also, getIndexedNodes() requires a key-value pair. Is there any way to get all, or a subset of the items in the index without looping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the authors/maintainers of node-neo4j here. =)

> indexedNodes don't get defined. I've tried a few different combinations. No joy. How do I use this command?

Your example seems to have some syntax errors. Are `index1`, `username` and `Homer` variables defined elsewhere? Assuming not, i.e. assuming those are the actual index name, property name and value, they need to be quoted as string literals, e.g. `'index1'`, `'username'` and `'Homer'`. But you also have a colon right before the opening parenthesis that shouldn't be there. (That's what's causing the Node.js REPL to not understand your command.)

Then, note that `indexedNodes` **should** be `undefined` -- `getIndexedNodes()`, like most Node.js APIs, is asynchronous, so its return value is `undefined`. Hence the callback parameter.

You can see an example of how `getIndexedNodes()` is used in the sample [node-neo4j-template](https://github.com/aseemk/node-neo4j-template) app the README references:

https://github.com/aseemk/node-neo4j-template/blob/2012-03-01/models/user.js#L149-L160

> Also, getIndexedNodes() requires a key-value pair. Is there any way to get all, or a subset of the items in the index without looping?

`getIndexedNodes()` does return all matching nodes, so there's no looping required. Getting a subset isn't supported by Neo4j's REST API directly, but you can achieve the result with [Cypher](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/cypher-query-lang.html).

E.g. to return the 6th-15th user (assuming they have a `type` property set to `user`) sorted alphabetically by username:

```
db.query([
  'START node=node:index1(type="user")',
  'RETURN node ORDER BY node.username',
  'SKIP 5 LIMIT 10'
].join('\n'), callback);
```

Cypher is still rapidly evolving, though, so be sure to reference the documentation that matches the Neo4j version you're using.

As mentioned above, in general, take a look at the sample [node-neo4j-template](https://github.com/aseemk/node-neo4j-template) app. It covers a breadth of features that the library exposes and that a typical app would need.

Hope this helps. =)

Comment: I realised node-neo4j supported Cypher shortly after I sent this. I figured my syntax was wrong, and the webadmin console helps a lot in figuring it out. Thanks a lot for the comprehensive answer!

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j 2 lets you do indices VIA REST. Docs here

[REST Indicies](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-unique-indexes.html)